# Android table column width 50 / 50

Tags: android, xml, layout

i have this table layout:

```
<TableRow 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:text="test"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" android:background="#b0b0b0"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="left"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:text="Row 3 column 2"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" android:background="#a09f9f"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="left"/>  
</TableRow>
```

I would like to have each column exactly 50 percent of the width.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 18):

Use this construction (layout for one row):

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</TableRow>
```

Comment: I've edited my answer. The main idea is to use android:weightSum and android:layout_weight with android:layout_width="0dp"

Comment: wightSum is optional when its value is the same as the sum of all weights